# Adobe Reader not following tab order for interactive PDF set in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat, interactive

I have set a tab order for an interactive PDF in Indesign. See order below.

[image: tab order]

When I start pressing tab from **advance shipment Booth #** it starts to work OK but goes from **Direct Shipment Booth #** to **Shipped from State** when it should be going to **Shipped from City** first.

[image: tab order demo]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your hierarchy is in the same order as your tabs? That could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set your own tab order, make sure to **turn off** "use Structure for Tab Order" when exporting the interactive PDF.

See below for my export options for an interactive PDF.

[image: export options for PDF]